# Are there male witches (warlocks) in The Witches?

Tags: the-witches

I know that the beginning says

> There is no such thing as a male witch

but there ARE, called warlocks. Take Ben Ravencroft from Scooby Doo and the Witch's Ghost for example.

Also, in the film adaptation of *The Witches*, the "witches" in the back rows were played by men, so could THEY possibly be warlocks?

Comment: _"Take Ben Ravencroft from Scooby Doo and the Witch's Ghost for example."_ You can't really use a completely different work to justify why something might exist in another work, the two are not related.

Answer (score 16):

A fundamental problem that you face is that the lore of the book makes it clear that the witches are not, in fact, human, as per his Grandmamma's account:

> "They look like women. They talk like women. And they are able to act like women. But in actual fact, they are totally different animals. They are demons in human shape"

So, aside from the issue of trying to invoke a concept of "warlocks" from another work, you're trying to impose human standards of sex and gender on the witches, who are not human.

Comment: Well, animals aren’t human and they’re either male or female.

Comment: @AlexDowns: Not all of them. :) https://medium.com/@tippykiyay/non-binary-in-nature-3e59675c85d3

Comment: @AlexDowns here you have an example of female-only reptile https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/asexual-lizards/